# Functions Delete data from database

Tags: php, function, web

I got problem here when I trying to delete some my character database through the User Control Panel Website.

Here is my function codes :

```
function DeleteChar() {
global $pdo;
if($_POST['name'] !== ''&& $_POST['characterid'] !== ''){
    $charname = $_POST['name'];
    $delchar = $_POST['characterid'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `name` = :namechar");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':namechar' => $charname
    ));
        if($_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 5 || $_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 10) {
                $query2 = $pdo->prepare("DELETE from `characters` where `characters`.`characterid` = :del_char and `name`= :namechar");
                $query2->execute(array(
                    ':del_char' => $delchar,
                    ':namechar' => $charname
                    ));

     if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            Logs(2, "Successfully deleted the character from the database");
            GetMessage("Congratulation!", "Successfully deleted ". $charname . " ! ", 3);
        }
        else {
            GetMessage("Oh snap!", "Failed to delete" . $charname . " from the database!", 1);
            }
    }   
    else {
        GetMessage("Oops!", "Unable to delete the character from the database!", 1);
        }
}
else {
    GetMessage("Oh snap!", "Character name is empty!", 1);
    }
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2'>";
}
```

the `$_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 5 || $_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 10` is just for spesific admin level who can try do delete the char from the database.

My table `characters` are filled with `'name' 'characterid' and 'userid'`

I tried it almost two days, and didn't know where exactly the problem is.

Anyway, I have similiar `functions` with this one and that's working

```
function RemoveStaff() {
global $pdo;
if($_POST['forumname'] !== '') {
    $forumname = $_POST['forumname'];
    if($_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 9 || $_SESSION['adminlvl'] == 10) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `adminlvl` = '0' WHERE `user` = :username");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $forumname
        ));
        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            Logs(2, "Successfully kicked " . $forumname . " from the staff team");
            GetMessage("Congratulation!", "Successfully kicked " . $forumname . " from the staff team!", 3);
        }
        else {
            GetMessage("Oh snap!", "Failed to kick user from the staff team!", 1);
        }
    } 
    else {
        GetMessage("Oops!", "Unable to remove ".$forumname." from the staff team", 1);
    }
}
else {
    GetMessage("Oh snap!", "UCP name is empty!", 1);
}
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2'>";
}
```

the second one `function RemoveStaff()` is working, though. But the first is not working. I'd appreacite who can find out the problem.

Comment: In your first query, you wrote two `$` (in `':namechar' => $$charname`).

Comment: @iArcadia yeah thanks for the correction. But, still the same.

Comment: first I'd change !== to !=. Second I'd check what you are posting if it is visible inside the  function. Have you verified?

Comment: I was changed the `!==` to `!=` and nothing change at all. I don't, bro. @LelioFaieta

Comment: then check the values you post if they are received inside the function and if the db connection is established

Comment: @LelioFaietaok done, I dit it all. Nothiing change again, pfft. Also I have similiar coding from `function inviteStaff()` but it's working. And this one is the crazy one, didn't working.